# Custom CSS not loading on SOME pages - particularly those with forms?

Tags: css, magento2

So I installed Magento, extended the blank theme, and threw in a little bit of custom CSS... the CSS works on some pages, like the homepage, privacy policy, and catalog pages but doesn't work on others. It seems to have trouble on pages that have forms, such as the contact form, orders and returns, and advanced search pages. When I view source, the CSS reference is shown on the page.

I've put the CSS reference in both the HTML head section under content > Design > configuration. I've put the reference in default_head_blocks as well. I've tried flushing Magento's cache and erasing the var/cache folder.

default_head_blocks:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="[site].com/pub/media/kwesteb.css" media="screen and (min-width: 1px?)" />
        <css src="css/styles-m.css"/>
        <css src="css/styles-l.css" media="screen and (min-width: 768px)"/>
        <css src="css/print.css" media="print"/>
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

I expect the CSS to show on all pages, however it does not show on pages that have a contact form of some sort.

Comment: can you put default_head_blocks in your answer so I can get more Idea? If possible share the page which is not load css

Comment: Hello, I added it. These are the pages that won't load css: https://kwesteboutique.com/sales/guest/form/, https://kwesteboutique.com/contact/, https://kwesteboutique.com/catalogsearch/advanced/, at least the ones I've found so far. Thank you for taking a look at my problem.

Comment: this is <css src="[site].com/pub/media/kwesteb.css" media="screen and (min-width: 1px?)" /> wrong path

Comment: My CSS file is in pub/media. I saw it recommended in another post when I was researching how to fix this. And it IS working on some of my pages so I'm not sure the path is the issue. I've tried putting it in the CSS folder as well. Do you have any recommendations on how to fix it?

Comment: It is standard if you create your theme then put css or js in your theme folder

Answer (score 0):

You've set the css file up wrongly and it's trying to be applied twice.
You're trying to find it at `https://kwesteboutique.com/contact/pub/media/kwesteb.css` and `https://kwesteboutique.com/pub/static/version1569869554/frontend/Kweste/KwesteBtq/en_US/kwesteboutique.com/pub/media/kwesteb.css` The first url is because of the entry in design -> configuration, just delete that. The second is the broken reference in the default head blocks xml file.

Please move it to the correct place detailed below and fix the default_head_blocks.xml entry.

The file needs to be in `app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<theme>/css`

Change the xml file entry to: `<css src="css/kwesteb.css" media="screen and (min-width: 1px?)" />`

CSS files should be attached to a theme or a module not in pub/media.

If you are in developer mode, clear the cache load the page. If you are in production mode you'll need to deploy static content. The default way being `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`, if you use a custom script or something to deploy the content like that, do that instead.

Some advice in debugging this kind of issue. Check the inspector, if you have an error it's more than likely according to Magento, you've done something wrong. If it's CSS like this, you have MIME type errors, often that means it's not being referenced correctly or you have an url issue. If you look at the second url I mentioned that you have on the page, that refers to a file structure. ignore the version bit and then you can follow the structure from pub. If that's wrong you need to fix where the file is. Also remember that most if not all server systems are case sensitive on the file and folder names.